# Mariadb-server-10.1 on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, package-management

I upgraded to 17.10 recently, and everything went quite well.
But the said package (Mariadb-server-10.1) had some problems and was left unconfigured. I tried reconfiguring it later:

```
~ > sudo dpkg-reconfigure mariadb-server
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mariadb-server is broken or not fully installed
```

Then I tried to remove it and install again. Despite the fact that the package is marked with "C" in aptitude, it installs but then again fails to be configured.

What I find really weird is this:

[image]

Notice "*mariadb-server-10.1*" in the list of conflicting packages: it seems like the package is marked as conflicting with itself, isn't it?

In the meanwhile, mariadb server keeps working)) However, whenever I call apt to install/update/remove anything, it attempts to configure mariadb-server-10.1, hangs for a couple of minutes then fails, and this is extremely annoying.

Comment: *"I upgraded to 17.10 recently"* No, you didn't. To 16.10, maybe.

Comment: Aye, it's 17.04 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to find and uninstall all your mysql package on computer

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common;
sudo apt-get autoremove;
sudo apt-get autoclean;
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/;
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
```

After that try to install mariadb

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client;
```

Comment: I don't have any of mysql packages installed, I've been using mariadb for ages already.